# Does reduction of carbonyls using borohydride ever use NaOH in the reaction?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, organic-reduction

I was reading about borohydride reductions of aldehydes and ketones in one of the Clayden textbooks, and I saw that NaOH was used in the bottom reaction for some reason:
[image: the bottom reaction uses sodium hyrdoxide]

Is this really necessary? I know that usually we just use proton donors later on in the reaction to cap the alkoxide group but we have methanol and water for those. All the other examples seem to use either water or organic alcohols like methanol or ethanol, so why is NaOH being  used here?

Comment: Base helps to repress the slow reaction of NaBH4 (liberated BH3?) with alcohol, in particular methanol.